# Rotating point incorrectly

Tags: language-agnostic

was developing some circuitry simulation software but ran into a very simple school level problem. Rotating points, now I have done this before in xna like so: x=x*cos(theta)+offsetx y=y*sin(theta)+offsety. This didnt seem to work in this case, so i looked it up and apparently  it's:

I tried that aswell, issues again.

```
-1 : 0
 0 : 1
 1 : 0
 ======0.000======
0 : 0
-1 : -1
0 : 0
======1.571======
0 : 0
1 : 1
0 : 0
======3.142======
0 : 0
1 : -1
0 : 0
======4.712======
```

in format x:y then with the rotation angle in radians ====theta====
Those aren't the correct coordinates, Any help apreciated.

```
  Vector2[] vecs = new Vector2[3];
            vecs[0] = new Vector2(-1, 0);
            vecs[1] = new Vector2(0, 1);
            vecs[2] = new Vector2(1, 0);

                for (int i = 0; i < vecs.Length; i++)
                {
                    vecs[i].X = vecs[i].X * (float)Math.Cos(rotation) - vecs[i].Y * (float)Math.Sin(rotation);
                    vecs[i].Y = vecs[i].Y * (float)Math.Cos(rotation) + vecs[i].X * (float)Math.Sin(rotation);

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you rotate point (px, py) around point (ox, oy) by angle theta you'll get:

```
p'x = cos(theta) * (px-ox) - sin(theta) * (py-oy) + ox
p'y = sin(theta) * (px-ox) + cos(theta) * (py-oy) + oy
```

---

Then the algorithm is correct and you have problem elsewhere, ex: decimal point accurecy

```js
function rotate(point, theta, origin){
    origin = origin || [0, 0];
    return [
        Math.round((Math.cos(theta) * (point[0]-origin[0]) - Math.sin(theta) * (point[1]-origin[1]) + origin[0])*1000)/1000,
        Math.round((Math.sin(theta) * (point[0]-origin[0]) + Math.cos(theta) * (point[1]-origin[1]) + origin[0])*1000)/1000
    ]
}

$(function() {
  v = function() {
    var point = [
      parseFloat($("#inputx").val()),
      parseFloat($("#inputy").val())
    ]
    var angle = parseFloat($("#inputtheta").val());
    var result = rotate(point,angle);
    console.log(result)
    $("#result").text("["+result+"]");
  };
  $("#inputx").bind("change paste keyup", function() {v()});
  $("#inputy").bind("change paste keyup", function() {v()});
  $("#inputtheta").bind("change paste keyup", function() {v()});
  v();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<label for="inputx">X</label>
<input type="text" id="inputx" class="form-control" name="inputx" value="-1">
</div>

<div>
<label for="inputy">Y</label>
<input type="text" id="inputy" class="form-control" name="inputy" value="0">
</div>

<div>
<label for="inputtheta">Θ</label>
<input type="text" id="inputtheta" class="form-control" name="inputtheta" value="1.57079633">
</div>

<div>
<label>=</label>
<div id="result" ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: since im rotating around origin then that becomes
x'=cos(theta)*X-sin(theta)*Y
y'=sin(theta)*X+cos(theta)*Y
which is what i did

Comment: argh, I hate floating point inaccuracies, how would I get around that? Thanks by the way.

Comment: One way would be to round the result, ex: "Math.round(...*1000)/1000" that takes 3 significant digits and uses midpoint rounding "away from zero". Note that this can be "rounding to even" in language you use. Example "Math.round(3.5)" would be 3 instead 4.